# Regex matching a character in the middle of a string, but don't include it

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

"123456-54321"

Now I want to craete a regex that gives me back "12345654321". Also it would be nice if an input of "12345654321" would also give "12345654321" back. But for example an input of "123-7471233" would not give me a match.

Can this be done with regex? I couldn't make it work with positive or negative lookbehind. I am using .NET for the Regex library.

Thanks!

Comment: Regex is not what you want, use replace method of your language.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex

```
(\d{6})-?(\d{5})
```

and replace with `$1$2`

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d{6}-?(\d{5})", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\d{6})-(?=\d{5})
```

You can use this to get rid of `-`.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

https://regex101.com/r/nU1nJ3/1

Answer (score 0):

Another regex matching your pattern is ^[0-9]+-?[0-9]+$. It will recognize your string. But as was said before, probably you are looking for replacement, so after you recognize the string, you need to remove the dash sign. i.e. replace with nothing.